# Which is better, a single "insert select-join" (single query) or select and then insert (two queries)

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm collecting a lot of content about users. The content has an ownerID that is different from the ids I've provided to the owner. I also have a map of ownerId to my internal ids.
I'm conflicted if I should insert the content with a single query or two queries.

Test schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE map (
   internalId INT NOT NULL,
   ownerId INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (internalId),
   INDEX (ownerId) 
);

Create Table content (
  internalId INT NOT NULL,
  contentId INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (internalId, contentId)
 );

INSERT INTO map (internalId, ownerId) VALUES (1,100), (2,1000)
```

Option 1: Select the relevant rows from the map, then build an insert query.
Option 2: The following query works (the internal select statements with the UNION ALL are generated programmatically):

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO content (SELECT internalId, contentId FROM (SELECT 101 AS contentId, 100 AS ownerId UNION ALL
     SELECT 102 AS contentId, 100 AS ownerId UNION ALL
     SELECT 103 AS contentId, 100 AS ownerId UNION ALL
     SELECT 1001 AS contentId, 1000 AS ownerId) AS s_q
     INNER JOIN map USING (ownerId));
```

The second option is a bit faster (single query and all), but I haven't done any stress testing so not sure how it would handle cases where second table is locked due to inserts or updates.
The first option is easier to read and debug (and handle deadlocks - you just sort the data beforehand. I don't know if there are any guarantees in this regard about the second option).
Are there other aspects I haven't noticed?

Comment: The problem is that we cannot tell you which solution is better for **you**.

Comment: The question isn't exactly about which is better, but what would make one approach better than the other.
For example, if the probability of a connection error is P, then the first approach can fail with probability 2p-p^2 - so that should be considered.

Comment: You are overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the single query.

The reason is not “performance”, “simplicity” or “style” (although the single query wins on all counts)... it’s *data integrity*.

If you use 2 queries, there’s necessarily a time gap between them, within which another process could modify the data in such a way that your composed update no longer contains correct values for the new state of the database.

A single query is always has the correct effect.

You could start a transaction, lock all the tables involved, read, compose update query, execute update, commit, but that’s burdensome on both the developer and the database.